# Joda time pattern incorrect? Showing wrong day

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using the joda package to do some of my work with time. I am confused why my pattern isn't doing the correct job to get the correct day, which should be 10. If I print it out it shows:
what is the getDayOfMonth --> 14

```
public void testTime() {
        String startDate = "Fri, 10 Jan 2015 23:10:04 +0000";
        String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +xxxx";
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
        DateTime time1 = fmt.parseDateTime(startDate);
        System.out.println("what is the getDayOfMonth --> " + time1.getDayOfMonth());
    }
```

Is there an issue with EEE ? What would I need to do to fix it?

Comment: The 10 Jan 2015 wasn't a Friday. You must pass a correct date or ignore the day of week in your pattern.

Comment: You are using wrong format for timezone thing. Instead of `+xxxx` use just `Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you're using wrong pattern for timezone. Use `Z` instead of `+xxxx`. See [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) API.

Secondly, you should also specify timezone for your formatter, else it will format on your local timezone. So you might not get exactly `10`, if your timezone is `+5:00`. And of course, *10 Jan* was Saturday, not Friday. In all, the following should work fine:

```
String startDate = "Sat, 10 Jan 2015 23:10:04 +0000";
String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime time1 = fmt.parseDateTime(startDate);
System.out.println("what is the getDayOfMonth --> " + time1.getDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: Thank you @dystroy , yes my day was wrong

Comment: Thank you @Rohit Jain , I need to use Z. I made the fix so it became: String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";